# Return content-type in java server

Tags: java, java-server

NOTE : just to be clear , i know how to do the if statements. I need a way of getting the actual content type and storing that in a variable as a string.

I have written a simple java server . I haven't figured out how to return the content type of the file the server loads.

I know it there would be an if statement that would set a string variable to for example text/html based on what another variable e.g contetType is. 
So , for example :

```
if (contentType == ".html")
    {
        String s = "text/html";
    }
    else if ......
```

This is a section from the server (the code for an okay 200 response) :

```
         String okayreply="HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n" +
               "Content-Lenght : "+ file1.length() + 
               "Content-Type:" +
               "\r\n" +
               "\r\n" +
               "<h2>File Found</h2>\r\n";

    System.out.println(okayreply );
```

So I need to find the content type and store it in a variable . From that I can use that information to set the content type when the response message is displayed.

**EDIT , It just returns blank for the content type:**

```
File file1 = new File (filename);
String s = "";

  int indexOfFinalDot = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
if (indexOfFinalDot > 0) {
    String fileExtentsion = filename.substring(indexOfFinalDot).toLowerCase();
    if ("html".equals(fileExtentsion)) {
       s = "text/html";
    }
}
```

Also :

```
String okayreply="HTTP/1.0 200 OK \r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n" +
               "Content-Lenght : "+ file1.length() + "\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: " + s +
               "\r\n" +
               "\r\n" +
               "<h2>File Found</h2>\r\n";

    System.out.println(okayreply );
```

Comment: I sense you're reinventing the wheel here. ServletRequest class [already has a getContentType method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getContentType()).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to determine the content type of a file based on the file extension

Please note that the logic does try to guess the content type based on the filename. If the filename is wrong (no extension / wrong extension) the content-type header will most probably be wrong.

Assuming you have a file name somewhere:

```
    String filename = "index.html"; 

    int indexOfFinalDot = filename.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (indexOfFinalDot > 0) {
        String fileExtentsion = filename.substring(indexOfFinalDot + 1).toLowerCase();
        if ("html".equals(fileExtentsion)) {
           //your logic here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would this file object be suitable : File file1 = new File (filename);

Comment: updated the answer. You do not need the File object itself. You only need a filename

Comment: why does the filename string = index.html . What if the file is a text file or a jpg or the file isnt called index

Comment: it's just an example, as I do not know your code. If you have a filename already somewhere - use that String

Comment: for some reason its not working . Iv put an edit in my original post so you can see the code.

Comment: Are you sure that the filename is correct? Try System.out.println(fileExtension); to see what's actually where

Comment: when i try an compile , i get a cannot find symbol error for fileExtentsion

Comment: System.out.println(filename)

Comment: It prints our the folder the file is stored in aswell as the name : www/small.html